# Does a country really need a head of state?

Tags: government, politics

I want to make a parliamentary country. The head of the government is the premier. The premier and each minister are elected (or replaced) by the parliament during the legislature, whose the duration is 4 years. The chancellor is the minister of foreign affairs, which is also elected by the parliament.

I don't see any reasons to add a symbolic "head of state". My understanding is that this role manages the relations with other countries, but some in countries (Germany for instance), it is useless and decorative (like the British queen).

Because I have a minister of foreign affairs to represent the country to the other countries, there is no point in adding a ceremonial role.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a worldbuilding problem. Have you done any basic research before asking? Plenty of states, each with a head of state, a prime minister and a minister for foreign affairs around.

Comment: I don't see how this is off-topic. The OP might have English as a second language and/or just not entirely clear on the term/title "head of state". In answer, a "head of state" is generally the figure who represents the country to the rest of the world (state being another term for a sovereign nation). So, the king/queen/president is generally the "head of state". If your country has no figurehead/executive role like that, and their parliament is their primary government, then the prime minister (or whoever leads the parliament) would be the "Head of State".

Comment: Some coutries have a head of state who is also the head of government. In other countries these positions are different. In countries where the positions of head of state and head of government are distinguished, the powers and responsibilities of the head of state vary very widely, from very strong to very weak. But even a weak head of state has moral authority, and sometimes a head of state which is generally considered weak, as, for example, the President of Italy, can make effective use of their limited power, for example by refusing to appoint a particularly nasty Prime Minister.

Comment: Elaborating on why I don't feel this is off topic: if someone is wanting to solidly establish the socio-political atmosphere of their world (IMO a very often overlooked/handwaived detail that leads to endless plot holes), that is very much "worldbuilding."

Comment: The three roles have different functions. Premier can be the head of government. The minister for foreign affairs deals the nation's overseas relations with other nations. The head of state represents the whole as a whole. If your chancellor is both head of state and foreign minster, this is possible, but unlikely, then this is a dual role. Usually the two are separated and for good reasons. Usually heads of states are above ongoing day-to-day political affairs. Parliamentary govts work best with a head of state.

Comment: The British queen is not "useless".  Her position is apolitical, not favouring any particular party, and doesn't allow her to introduce new laws, but it does have one very powerful ability.  The head of state's duty is to defend the constitution and to ensure that parliament provides good government.  At any time, if the current leadership is not following the rules, the Queen can fire the entire government.  She then can either ask someone else (typically the leader of the opposition party) to form a new government, or call a general election to determine the will of the people.

Comment: @HA Harvey this one is a "real world" question, which _might_ be on topic here at Worldbuilding SE. However, the question right now does highlight any worldbuilding aspect, and more so, shows the lack of background research.

Comment: This would be on topic if the OP wishes to address the question from ***within the scope of a fictional world***.  As it stands, this is a googleable, government studies 101 question.  Once the OP has done some background research, then we'll be happy to help answer *application to fictional world questions!*

Comment: @L.Dutch, this is a worldbuilding problem. Because I don't see any reasons to have a "head of state", I need to see opinions about a country without it. I understand "Representation of the country to the rest of the world" as foreign affairs. Symbolic role is useless for me.

Comment: @Squall, the role of a head of state is defined in that country constitution. The role of the POTUS is different from the role of the Italian President of Republic and from the role of the President of France. Since laws are a convention between citizens in a given time and not general rules, I stay convinced this is not a worldbuilding problem and doesn't even have a measurable answer.

Comment: consider "the stanless steel rat goes to war"

Answer (score 4):

Your call, a fictional country can have any sort of practical or impractical arrangement.

Generally speaking, the distinction of "head of state" and "head of government" is to disconnect mostly ceremonial duties from the day-to-day business of government.

- Major states will have enough work to keep two people busy.
- A careful distribution of authority can create **checks and balances**. If the head of government does something unreasonable, the head of state may be able to step in, and vice versa.

The German Bundespräsident does not *manage* foreign affairs, he *signs* documents and *greets* foreign representatives. This role is not much different from the signing and publishing of domestic laws and appointments. The real management of foreign affairs is up to the foreign secretary under the overall policy guidance of the Bundeskanzlerin.